# Rewrite URLs with Nginx

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

I am running on Nginx and I am trying to create a blog that essentially works like this:

1. I create a new post with the title "How to Create a New Website" under the **"business" category**
2. I turn that title into a slug **how-to-create-a-new-website**
3. The final URL looks like this: http:://www.example.com/**blog**/**business**/**how-to-create-a-new-website**

So what I am trying to accomplish is this:

I have a single page that searches for the **category** and **slug** in my database. It retrieves that article and displays it. The **category** and **slug** should be able to be anything.

So what I need is a Nginx rewrite/location rule that will allow for this. I have successfully done something similar to this on another server with this Apache rewrite rule in my .htaccess file (but without the category):

```
#Clean URLs for Blog
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ blog/article.php?slug=$1 [L]
```

Everything I have tried on the Nginx server does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this rule:

```
Location ~ /blog/ {
   rewrite "^(/blog)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$" $1/article.php?category=$2&slug=$3 last;
}
```